# Using property values of pom.xml in application.properties

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I am trying to read values of pom.xml and inject it into application.properties. But I am not able to achieve this.
In my pom.xml, I have the property value like below:

```
<properties>
     <app.mobile.db.host>
        ${env.APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST}
    </app.mobile.db.host>
...
</properties>
```

And, APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST is coming from settings.xml of .m2 folder.
 I added the following lines in pom.xml also.

```
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
....
```

In application.properties I am accessing like

```
app.host= @app.mobile.db.host@
```

And in Spring boot I am using @ConfigurationProperties to read the value from application.properties.
But when I print it, it just prints @app.mobile.db.host@.
Where I am going wrong? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

`@` only works if you're using `spring-boot-starter-parent`. Also, if you want the value to come from `settings.xml`, you shouldn't redefine it in your `pom.xml`. Lastly, `env.x` syntax is for environment variables; removing that line from your pom and changing `application.properties` to `app.host = @APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST@` should solve the issue. If you absolutely must create an alias for `APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST`, define it like `app.host=${APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST}` in the `pom.xml`, although I'm not sure if Maven does multiple passes for property resolution.

Verify your changes by running `mvn resources:resources -DAPP_MOBILE_DB_HOST=test` and inspecting the `target/classes/application.properties`. You don't need to run the application.

Comment: I removed env.x line form pom.xml. And in the `application.properties` I am reading values like `app.host=${APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST}`. Still it is not working. In settings.xml the property is like this 
`<app.mobile.db.host>XXX</app.mobile.db.host>`

Comment: @ninja.bhaSiv read again, that's not what I said. If you can't follow these simple instructions, then I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added `spring-boot-starter-parent` in pom.xml. Then removed the `env.x` line. And in `application.properties` am accessing it as `app.host=@APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST@`. but it is not picking up the value

Comment: @ninja.bhaSiv Obviously, you'll need to have `APP_MOBILE_DB_HOST` in the `settings.xml`; I thought that was common sense, but...